# Prove $\varphi \colon (1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that for sufficient small $\varepsilon$ there exists a two times
>   differentiable function $\varphi \colon (1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon) \to
>  \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi(1)=0$ and $$ \cos (\varphi (x))-\varphi(x) =
>  x.$$

*My try:*
For a first year university question usually it has to with some theorem or another, so I first thought of the implicit function theorem. But it's a problem that you cannot really define an $F$, because the equation has the $\varphi (x)$ in it already.

Also, I have no idea how to find out how that equation behaves, because I don't know $\varphi$, which is what I'm searching for.

I don't know if such specific proofs are allowed/encouraged on this site? Please leave a comment if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the implicit function theorem. Say $$F(x,y)=\cos(y)-y-x.$$Then $F(1,0)=0$ and $F_y(1,0)=-1\ne0$, so IFT says precisely that there exists $\varphi$ defined near $1$ with $F(x,\varphi(x))=0$.

Comment: Oh wow, that's stupid of me... Writing it a little different had me confused... Of course $y=\phi (x)$....